# Validate date field

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to disable the save button untill date is not picked. it is disabled but its not able to enbale untill i dont press any key from the keyboard.please tell me what i am doing wrong and thanks in advance.

```
<div class = "form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : Form.fromTime.$invalid && !Form.fromTime.$pristine }">
    <label for = "fromTime"> From Time:
        <img src = "images/required.gif" alt = "Required" class = "required-star">
    </label>

    <div class='input-group date' id='fromTime'  >
        <input type='text' class="form-control" name="fromTime" ng-model = "fromTime" required />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
    </div>
    <p ng-show="Form.fromTime.$invalid && !Form.fromTime.$pristine" class="help-block">From Time is required.</p>
</div>

<button type="button" class="col-sm-2 btn btn-primary" ng-click="scheduleCall()" style="margin-left:10px;" ng-disabled="Form.$invalid"> Save </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
ng-disabled="Form.$invalid"
```

to:

```
ng-disabled="Form.fromTime.$invalid"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like below

```
ng-disabled="Form.fromTime.$invalid"
```

Formname: Form;
Input field name : fromTime;
Input field state: $invalid

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you need to use a `date` input.

Now `save` button will be disabled until a valid date is picked.

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.fromTime = '';

  $scope.scheduleCall = function() {};

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form name="Form">
      <div class="form-group" 
           ng-class="{ 'has-error' : Form.fromTime.$invalid && !Form.fromTime.$pristine }">

        <label for="fromTime">From Time:</label>

        <div class='input-group date' id='fromTime'>
          <input type='date' class="form-control" name="fromTime" ng-model="fromTime" required />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <p ng-show="Form.fromTime.$invalid && !Form.fromTime.$pristine" 
           style="font-size: 11px; color: red;">
          From Time is required.
        </p>
      </div>

      <button type="button" ng-click="scheduleCall()" ng-disabled="Form.$invalid">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @avi Edited, is this what you wanted to achieve?